# Insert multiple inputs on one line in C++

Tags: c++, input, iostream

I'm trying to insert multiple inputs on one line, with comma and a space between the inputs. The method I've been using so far separates inputs with spaces.

```
int a, b , c ,d
cin >> a >> b >> c >> d ;
```

With this method , the input line looks like this :

```
1 2 3 4
```

But I want to be able to input data like this:

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

Comment: Are you trying to perform input or output? You seem like you've been trying input, where you want to perform output.

Comment: I need to input all the data on one line , not to output the data.

Comment: The "correct" way to get input in C++ is to read _whole lines_ into a `string`, and then to parse that `string` in a specialised fashion.

Comment: I'm fairly new to programming and I haven't used string so far , so I really don't know how to do that. *googling for strings*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The delimiter character for `>>` isn't modifiable, but you can use it in combination with `ignore`:

```
std::cin >> a;
std::cin.ignore(1, ',')

// rinse and repeat
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
int main() {
        int a,b,c,d;
        char comma;
        std::cin >> a >> comma >> b >> comma >> c >> comma >> d;
        std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << " " << d << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4
```

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/tXQZd

Comment: Your code is restrictive because there is no comma inserted it would fail to run properly. But if there will always be a comma as separator I would use your snippet.

Comment: @mmimaa: Yes, that is true. But my post is an answer to your question. No more, no less.

Answer (score 0):

In C / C++, you only need do this:

```
scanf("%d, %d, %d, %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
```

You only need include the `<cstdio>`

Answer (score 0):

You can just proceed in this way -

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            /* code */
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                /* code */
                cin >> arr[i][j];
    
                cin.ignore(1, ' ');
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
```

This will take a 6*6 array input as

-9 -9 -9 1 1 1

0 -9 0 4 3 2

-9 -9 -9 1 2 3

0 0 8 6 6 0

0 0 0 -2 0 0

0 0 1 2 4 0

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, run a loop on the input and put all the input in a array/vector then use that array/vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    int num;

    // Read inputs until the end of the line
    while (std::cin >> num) {
        numbers.push_back(num);

        // Check for newline character or end of file
        if (std::cin.peek() == '\n' || std::cin.peek() == EOF)
            break;
    }

    // Print the numbers
    for (int i : numbers) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```